# Best way, how to find word in dictionary

Tags: java, find

what is best way how to find word in big dictionary?

I have one word for example `dog` and i want to check, if is this word in my dictionary - only `true, false`. Is there any better way then `binary search`?

Java pls :-)

Comment: The question as written is too broad.  You need to specify the detailed requirements in the question.  Like where the dictionary is to start with, and what its form / format are, and how many times you need to do lookups and how much setup time and memory you are prepared to use and ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), to check for a word existence in O(1):

```
Set<String> dict = new HashSet<String>();

dict.add("dog");
dict.add("cat");

System.out.println(dict.contains("dog")); // true
```

If you want to create you own structures, you can also have a look at [Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and [DAWGs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph).